# Run injected JavaScript script only once WKWebView web page has fully loaded

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, load, wkwebview

I want to run a particular script in WKWebView only once the webpage has fully loaded (including images). What I've been doing so far is running the function `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` and calling `self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(...)` within `didFinish`, but I've noticed that `didFinish` fires before the web page has fully loaded. To run my code correctly, I've been using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.6)` to delay the function and give the web page enough time to download the content; however, I'd like a more standardized version of this – if the WiFi connection is slow, for example, then the delay isn't enough to prevent the function from firing.

How can I wait to fire my `webView.evaluateJavaScript(...)` until the web page has fully loaded?

This is what I've attempted so far, but it's not working at all:

```
self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("function getHTML() { return document.documentElement.innerHTML; } window.onload = getHTML", completionHandler: { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in`
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a WkUserScript first with your script -

```
let script = WKUserScript(
        source: yourScript,
        injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd,
        forMainFrameOnly: true
    )
```

then add that to WKUserContentController =

```
let controller = WKUserContentController()
controller.addUserScript(script)
```

after that create WKWebViewConfiguration -

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.userContentController = controller
```

and finally add that to your webView during initialization -

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: webViewOutletThatYouCreated.bounds, configuration: config)
```